# What is this tall plant?

Tags: identification

I'm hoping someone can help me identify this plant, so I can look into the best way to care for it and bring it back from the brink.

It's been in my family for at least 12 years, and maybe a lot longer than that. It also seems to be fairly resilient, because it's been through years of subpar care. When in good health, it's at least a few feet tall, with long leaves, and (possibly) can take up a lot of space.

I can research and ask about care once I know what it is, but if someone wants to link to any particular resources when answering here, I would appreciate that.

Let me know if you have any questions or want any more photos.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like a dead Dracaena (Dragon Plant). Those limbs rot from the inside out.

Comment: It's not totally dead. Those tiny leaves in the second-to-last photo have some green and are growing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very likely a Dracaena type, maybe marginata , especially if leaf edges were redish color. It looks pretty far gone with the wrinkled bark, they can grow from dead looking wood. Normally very tolerant, my biggest problem is deciding what to cut off when bringing it in from the deck for the winter.

Comment: It's mostly pretty limber, which gave me hope that it might have enough life to come back.

Comment: Ooh, [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracaena_(plant)#/media/File:Dracaena_ellenbeckiana_-_Jard%C3%ADn_Bot%C3%A1nico_Canario_Viera_y_Clavijo_-_Gran_Canaria.jpg) of a Dracaena ellenbeckiana looks quite familiar. Also pictures of marginata's.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a Dracaena or Cordyline.
The growth habit in branching looks more like a Cordyline to me. But my first thought was a Dracaena like others here.
Not looking in great shape though is it?!